# Express - Conditional Routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

At my `website.com/v2/bridge/:locationId/process` endpoint, the incoming `req.body` looks like this:

```
{
  choice: 'a',
  data: [
    {
      ...
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I want to access a particular route depending on what the value of `req.body.choice` is. If `req.body.choice === 'a'` then I want to go on to `website.com/v2/bridge/:locationId/process/choiceA` with the same `req` being passed on.

I don't know what middleware I need to use to accomplish that. I don't know if that is even possible.

My extremely simplified routes:

```
// website.com/v2/bridge
const proc = require('./process');

router.use('/:locationId/process', proc);

module.exports = router;




// website.com/v2/bridge/56/process
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // ?????????????????????????

  next();
});

const choiceA = require('./choice-a');
const choiceB = require('./choice-b');

router.use('/choice-a', choiceA);
router.use('/choice-b', choiceB);

module.exports = router;





// website.com/v2/bridge/56/process/choice-a
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('I got here.');

  return;
});

module.exports = router;
```

What middleware function do I need to include to conditionally route my request? I am trying to avoid one giant function with if statements that process different things according to the value of `req.body.choice`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be little trickier for you...give it a try

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.path = "/" + "choice-"+req.body.choice
  req.url = "/" + "choice-"+req.body.choice
  next();
});
```

now it'will do the request to the end point you want

Comment: I couldn't change `req.path`, but I was able to reassign `req.url` and that worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Great job, this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 5):

As part of finding the answer for the same question, I came across with this question, which didn't settle my mind by messing with the req.url, so here's how I got it done (I know it's a long delay, but better late than never):

When you're dealing with routers, and you want to make a condition to decide whether to use, you can do it with two ways (according to expressjs [doc](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router)), and let's learn them by examples

### 1. Skipping between routes

```js
function skipThisRouteMiddleware (req, res, next) {
    if (true === isAmazingValidation) {
        return next('route');
    }

    return next();
}

router.get('/user/:id',
    skipThisRouteMiddleware,
    getUserV1 // TBD - your old route
)

router.get('/user/:id',
    getUserV2 // TBD - your new route
)
```

In the case above, when you have two routes, and you want to conditionally pick one of them, it can be done by specifying a middleware that makes the validation for the first route only, and when needed, it triggers `next('route')` which skip to the next *matching* route, please note that you must specify METHOD and not generally `app.use()`

### 2. Skipping between routers

```js
// routers/index.js
const mainRouter = express.Router();
mainRouter.use(oldRouter);
mainRouter.use(newRouter);


// routers/old.js
const oldRouter = express.Router();

function canUpgradeToNewRouter (req, res, next) {
    if (true === isAmazingValidation) {
        return next('router'); // now it's 'router' and not 'route'
    }

    return next();
}

oldRouter.use(canUpgradeToNewRouter);


// routers/new.js
const newRouter = express.Router();

newRouter.use(...);
```

In this case, you have two different routers, and you want to conditionally pick one of them. for this case, you'll have to create a parent router (mainRouter) and two nested routers (oldRouter, newRouter).
The trick here is that the `oldRouter` tries to run a middleware validation that tries to "upgrade" the requester to the new shiny router, if the condition is true, it will skip the whole `oldRouter`, and pass the stick to the parent router `mainRouter` to continue matching routes to this request (the magic - `next('router')`), which eventually pick the upcoming `newRouter`

In both methods, we let the first route to make the logic and choose between itself and the others, that's a different perception (a bit)

Comment: This seems more viable, would try it out for my project and get back to you, I have been having a problem like this

Comment: What exactly is ```next('router') ```, can that name be changed or is it a standard?
For me, I am changing between 3 routers, and they are all separate files.
Hence the first two routes will have the switching logic in them. 

But I need to know exactly what to pass in the first call to ```next()```, must it be 
```next('router')``` , or the name of the router file

Comment: @Alara_stealth the `router` is a constant, just like the `route`. in your case, it doesn't matter what is the file structure but the `app.use()` order (each `next('router')` will bump to the next "use") regardless of the name of the files. unfortunately, it seems like they're not supporting named routes and jumping to them

Comment: Hence we have to follow a syntactical order?
I hope with time it can also be passed directly to the route names

Comment: Slight headache here @molaga The logic I am basing my conditional on rests in a mongo DB collection ```(if the user. status === 'teacher')```. Obviously, this is a DB call and has to be done asynchronously. I am trying to figure out how to first get this criteria declared, so I can easily reference it.

Comment: async function shouldRouterChange(req, res, next) {
        try {
            let userRole = await studentProfile.findOne({status:req.user.role});
            // conditional
            if (userRole==='teacher') {
                return next('router')
           }
.........


I get this error  :    Cannot read property 'role' of undefined

Comment: Was finally able to implement this, it switches to the next router alright, but then I repeat the middleware function in the second router too, so there could be a switch to a third router if the new condition passes, but this did not work, it goes back to the first router